# Type parameter has a circular constraint and Type does not satisfy the constraint 'object'

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am working on upgrading a project from Node 13 to higher versions and have encountered an issue - in the following code:

```
export function ConstructNotificationsObservable<TKVMap extends KeyValueMapGenericConstraint<TKVMap>>(
  instance: INotificationsObservable<TKVMap>,
  context: IObservableContext<KeyValueMapToNotifications<TKVMap>>,
  create?: (context: INotificationsObservableContext<TKVMap>) => TNotificationsObservableHook<TKVMap> | void
): void {
  ConstructClassWithPrivateMembers(instance, NOTIFICATIONS_OBSERVABLE_PRIVATE);
  const privates: INotificationsObservablePrivate<TKVMap> = (instance as INotificationsObservableInternal<TKVMap>)[NOTIFICATIONS_OBSERVABLE_PRIVATE];

  privates.context = context;
  privates.observersMap = new Map<KeyValueMapKeys<TKVMap>, KeyValueMapToNotificationsObservers<TKVMap>[]>();
  privates.othersObservers = [];

  InitObservableHook(
    instance,
    privates,
    NewNotificationsObservableContext,
    create,
  );
}
```

where KeyValueMapGenericConstraint is declared in the following way:

```
export type KeyValueMapGenericConstraint<TKVMap extends object> = KeyValueMapConstraint<TKVMap, KeyValueMapGeneric>;
```

I'm getting two errors:

```
TS2313: Type parameter 'TKVMap' has a circular constraint.
```

and

```
TS2344: Type 'TKVMap' does not satisfy the constraint 'object'.
```

And this is how the ConstructNotificationsObservable function is used in code:

```
ConstructNotificationsObservable<TKVMap>(this, context, create);
```

Weirdest part is that it works in Node 13, but not in Node 14.
I'm not quite sure how I can approach this.

This is a Node module that I'm using in several projects that I have to update to lates versions of Node. Code available here:
[GitHub source code](https://github.com/lifaon74/observables)

Comment: Is this a [mre]? Right now your `ConstructNotificationsObservable` declaration has invalid syntax (you can't put `extends object` where it is there).  If that's the problem then the answer is that your code is invalid and would fail in any version of TypeScript. If it's not, then please [edit] so your code is a [mre] that only has the problem you're talking about.

Comment: @jcalz, made the update to the original post.

Comment: @jcalz, this is not my work, I have taken over several projects that use this node module and I have to update the said projects to latest versions of Node, but I can't as this module stops working after Node 14.
Added a link to GitHub

Comment: `function ConstructNotificationsObservable<TKVMap extends KeyValueMapGenericConstraint<TKVMap extends object>>` is not and has never been valid TypeScript syntax.  The `extends object` doesn't belong there.  If it "worked" before it's accidental. You should approach it by having the upstream dependency patched or forking it. Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, I don't have enough knowledge in Node to be able to solve this syntax error. If you could provide some kind of solution, I'd greatly appreciate it.
As for upstream dependency, I have forked it, because I have a feeling that the original project is now abandoned (2 years since last update).
Thank you again for your help

Comment: Ugh, but [hey look that's not the upstream code at all](https://github.com/lifaon74/observables/blob/5e52429fef114ae33ce9b00c3d36d4e5e612ba3a/src/notifications/core/notifications-observable/constructor.ts#L20).  Where is the `extends object` from your code above? I have no advice because you haven't actually produced a [mre] I can look at. I'm going to disengage as my knowledge of Node is minimal and the code here doesn't actually represent the issue you're seeing.

Comment: @jcalz, huh, that's really bizzare, how come it checks out with `extends object`?.. (rhetorical question). I'll probably edit the question as I'm still left with both errors after removing `extends object`.